# Explanation of use of chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm reading *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring W. Tu and I'm not sure how the chain rule is used in the one of it's first equations. It goes as follows:

> By the chain rule,
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}f(p+t(x-p))=\sum (x^i-p^i)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p+t(x-p)).$$

To me, it looks like the summand is of the form $\frac{dl}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, where $l=p+t(x-p)$, rather than $\frac{df}{dl}\frac{dl}{dt}$, which makes more sense to me. Where am I going wrong in my thinking?  Thanks!

Comment: With $\phi(t) = p+t(x-p)$ you have $Df \circ \phi (t) = Df(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$, and since I am assuming things are real, you can write it as $(\phi'(t))^T  (D f(\phi(t)))^T$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it does look to me that the author has introduced a clash of variables by having both $x$ in the formula $x + t(x-p)$ and $x^i$ in the formula $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$.

So I agree with your assessment of introducing a vector valued variable $l=(l^1,...,l^n)$ as the "middle variable" of the chain rule. That variable should be used as an independent variable for $f=f(l)$, and as a dependent variable where $l^i = l^i(t) = p^i + t(x^i - p^i)$.

Using $l$, the summand in Tu's formula becomes $\displaystyle\frac{dl^i}{dt} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial l^i}$, not $\displaystyle\frac{dl}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ as suggested in your post. I prefer writing it in the other order as $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial l^i} \cdot \frac{dl^i}{dt}$.

The chain rule formula as a whole can then be written as a dot product
\begin{align*}
\frac{df}{dt} &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial l^i} \cdot \frac{dl^i}{dt} \\
&= \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial l^1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial l^n}\right)}_{\displaystyle=\frac{df}{dl}} \cdot \underbrace{\left(\frac{dl^1}{dt},...,\frac{dl^n}{dt}\right)}_{\displaystyle=\frac{dl}{dt}} 
\end{align*}
(The comment of @copper.hat is more formally correct, treating $\frac{df}{dl}$ as a linear transformation in the form of an $n \times 1$ matrix, and treating the chain rule as a matrix multiplication formula; but I wanted to write it this way to lay out in detail the role of $l$ and its components).

In general, the derivative symbols that we make up are really just shorthands for some more formal expression, even the symbol $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the ordinary derivative. In this case the derivative symbol $\frac{df}{dl}$, with a real valued symbol $f$ in the numerator and a vector valued symbol $l$ in the denominator, is just a shorthand for a vector of ordinary partial derivative symbols $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial l_1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial l_n})$, where $l_1,...,l_n$ are independent real valued variables.  = p_i + t (x_i-p_i)$.

So, to address your question in the comments, $\frac{dl}{dt}$ has the value given above because that's what its value has to be in order that one can write the chain rule in shorthand as
$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{df}{dl} \frac{dl}{dt}
$$
And, referring again to the "clash of variables" issue, I don't think the terms in the formula for $\frac{df}{dl}$ should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, then should instead by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial l^i}$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly explain why $\frac{df}{dl}=(\frac{df}{dx_1},...,\frac{df}{dx_n})$? I guess that’s where my confusion comes from.

Comment: I did a rewrite of my answer, to try to address your comment more directly. And to correctly use partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial l_i$ rather than ordinary derivatives $df/dl_i$.