# Difficulty understanding Chain rule in multivariable calculus

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, chain-rule

I am having difficulty understanding the following form of the chain rule. Let $f$ be a function, whose arguments are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, I have read (in the book "Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu, pg.6) that the chain rule takes the following form
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\Big(p^i+t(x^i-p^i)\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^n
(x^i-p^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f\Big(p^i+t(x^i-p^i)\Big)$$
where $t$ is a scalar quantity taking the values from 0 to 1.

If I were to apply the chain rule, I would set, for example, $u^i=p^i+t(x^i-p^i)$ and then write down that
$$\frac{d}{dt}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}$$
and hence
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\Big(p^i+t(x^i-p^i)\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}f\Big(p^i+t(x^i-p^i)\Big)\tag{*}\label{*}$$
which is not the same, according to my understanding, to the one I find in the book, since I $f$ in my case is differentiated with respect to the vector $u^i=p^i+t(x^i-p^i)$, whereas in the book's case the differentiation of $f$ is simply with respect to $x^i$. **So, my guess is that the two differentiations must be equivalent or at least somehow related. Can someone explain why??**

P.S.: I have seen [Explanation of use of chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482928/explanation-of-use-of-chain-rule), in which the answer claims that - according to my definition of $u^i$ - the answer should be given as in $\eqref{*}$, but I am not sure whether or not I am convinced as to why something like that should hold?

Comment: In Loring & Tu *Introduction to Manifolds* the formula on p. 6 has no upper index $i$ on the LHS. Ditto inside $f$ on the RHS. Another hint: with your $u^i$ what is $\partial u^i/\partial t$ ?

Comment: There is no upper index $i$ on the LHS, but it is implied that the quantities inside except from $t$ are vectors, right? And $\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial t}=x^i-p^i$, no?

Comment: Right and yes. -

Comment: So, I am allowed to write the expressions as I have written them in the post. However, I can not understand how the chain rule is performed exactly...

Comment: Can you apply the chain rule to $f(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$ ? And why absolutely this has to be written as $f(x_i(t))$ ? This might be the reason where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I was trying to ask why you put an index $i$ into $f$ which is different from Loring and Tu. Perhaps more important than that is if @PaulFrost 's answer can be accepted by you now. If not why not asking more specific questions ?

Comment: I am trying to determine the source of my missunderstanding. Yes, it seems that my confusion is related to the notation. Why am I not allowed to put indices to the arguments of $f$? They are spacetime points, aren't they? So, they should be labelled by $n$ set of coordinates each

Comment: I guess my question can be reduced to this: is $x$ inside the argument of the function $f$ the same as the $x^i$ used to label the coordinates?

Comment: Strictly speaking (this is MSE not PSE), $x$ inside $f$ is a multivalued function $x(t)=(x^1(t),...,x^n(t))$ and yes, $x^i(t)$ are the coordinates of the vector $x(t)$. When it comes to understanding a chain rule in such detail (worth doing) I would avoid sloppy notation and write a vector as a vector and a coordinate as a coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first observe that Tu writes
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\Big(p+t(x-p)\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^n
(x^i-p^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f\Big(p+t(x-p)\Big)$$
which is not the same formula as in your question.

I think your difficulty in understanding the chain rule in multivariable calculus is just a notational issue.

Tu considers $f : U \to \mathbb R$, where $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and star-shaped with respect to a point $p \in U$. This function has partial derivatives $D^if = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ which are again functions $U \to \mathbb R$. We shall write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \mid_\xi$ for the value $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} (\xi)$ of this function at $\xi \in U$. This is the standard notation, the symbol $\partial x^i$ is used because we usually write $f$ as a function $f(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ of $n$ variables $x^1, \ldots, x^n$. But the *naming* of the the variables is arbitrary, you can equally well view $f$ as a function of $n$ variables $u^1,\ldots,u^n$ which gives $D^if = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u^i}$ instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$. If there are three variables, it is also common to write $f(x,y,z)$ and $D^1f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $D^2f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $D^3f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

In the one-dimensional case we usually write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{d f}{dx}$ provided we regard $f$ as a function $f(x)$ of the variable $x$. But of course we can also write $f$ in the form $f(t)$ which erforces to write $\frac{d f}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{d f}{dx}$.

In other words, the naming of the variables in the domain of $f$ correponds $1$-$1$ to the naming of the "denominators" of the partial derivatives $D^if$. If the $i$-th variable is named $v$, then the associated partial derivative is named $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$.

Whatever you personal notational favourite may be, the point is that $D^if$ is the partial derivative of $f$ **with respect to the $i$-th coordinate**.

Let us come to Tu.

Define $u : (-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon) \to \mathbb R^n, u(t) = p + t(x-p)$. For sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$ the image of $u$ is contained in $U$ and we shall write $u : (-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon) \to  U$.
We can apply the chain rule to $f \circ u : (-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon) \to  \mathbb R$. We get
$$\frac{d(f \circ u)}{dt}\mid_{\tau} = Jf \mid_{u(\tau)} \circ Ju \mid_{\tau}$$where $Jf \mid_{u(\tau)}$ is the Jacobian matric of $f$ at $u(\tau)$ and $Ju \mid_{\tau}$ is the Jacobian matric of $u$ at $\tau$. We have
$$Ju \mid_\tau = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{d u^1}{dt}\mid_\tau  \\ \ldots \\ \frac{d u^n}{dt}\mid_\tau \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x^1 - p^1  \\ \ldots \\ x^n - p^n \end{pmatrix} $$
$$Jf \mid_{u(\tau)} = \begin{pmatrix}D^1f\mid_{u(\tau)}  & \ldots & D^nf\mid_{u(\tau)} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}\mid_{u(\tau)}  & \ldots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}\mid_{u(\tau)} \end{pmatrix}$$
Multiplying the matrices yields
$$\frac{d(f \circ u)}{dt}\mid_{\tau} = \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i-p^i)D^if\mid_{u(\tau)} = \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i-p^i)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\mid_{u(\tau)} .$$
This is exactly the same as your formula (*) since $\frac{d u^i}{dt} = x^i  - p^i$; the only formal difference is that you denote the coordinates of points of $U$ by $u^i$ instead of $x^i$. But I would not do that in the present case. As you define the $u^i$, they are *functions* of $t$ (involving parameters $x, p$ with do not depend on $t$), and the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u^i}$ may be confusing though formally correct.

Comment: The parameters $x$ and $p$ you refer to are actually points in space, having their own coordinates, i.e. $x^i=(x^1,...,x^n)$ and $p^i=(p^1,...,p^n)$, correct? How are these $t$ dependent? When I see fig. 1.3, I can only understand that we have parametrized coordinates with $t$, such that we can move from $p$ to $x$ simply by increasing $t$

Comment: Is $x$ a point in the Fig. 1.3 or is it the coordinate label? I am confused

Comment: @schris38 $x$ and $p$ are points of $U$ with coordinate representations $x=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ and $p=(p^1,\ldots,p^n)$. They do not depend on $t$, but the points on the line segment from $p$ to $x$ (which is contained in $U$ since $U$ is star-shaped with respect to $p$) is parameterized by $t$, i.e. by $u(t)=p+t(x-p)$. As you say, we can move from $p$ to $x$ simply by increasing $t$ from $0$ to $1$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $u(t)\in U$ for $t\in J=(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. Thus $u$ is defined on an **open** interval which allows to differentiate it in all $t\in J$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think now it's a bit more clear.

Comment: Last comment, and appologies for all the questions. So, from what I have come to understand, the differentiation wrt $x^i$ simply means differentiation wrt the coordinate label and this has nothing to do with the point $x$, correct? Then, after taking this partial derivative of $f$ wrt the coordinates, we evaluate the derivative to the point $p+t(x-p)=\Big(p^1+t(x^1-p^1),...,p^n+t(x^n-p^n)\Big)$. Is this picture I am getting correct? So, in other words, (partial) differentiation wrt the coordinates has nothing to do with the point $x$. They just happen to be represented by the same symbol?

Comment: @schris38 Yes, correct! That is why I wrote $D^if$ for the partial partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$-th coordinate. The variable name in $\partial x^i$ is completely irrelevant and may sometimes even be confusing. It has nothing to do with the $i$-th coordinate of a **specific** point $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Okay thank you so much Paul!!